# Ubuntu freezes on Acer Aspire E5-523-66XR (touchpad causing the issue?)

Tags: dual-boot, touchpad, freeze

Ubuntu 16.04.3 freezes after a few minutes of use. It freezes randomly after a few minutes of use, independently of what applications are being used. Usually the whole system freezes, the mouse moves but nothing else responds (not even Alt+SysRq+REISUB). I am installing it alongside Windows, which works fine. So far I tried all the below, without any effect:

- different bios boot configurations (with secure boot disabled and enabled, running UEFI and legacy)
- I flashed bios to the newest version
- different partition settings
- I installed Linux Mint 18.3 with Cinamon
- I tried to spot if any process is using many system resources, but all seems fine.

None of these made any effect and after each new installation of Ubuntu the problem continued.

**Touchpad?**

Last night I tried changing the UEFI "Touchpad" setting, from "basic" to "advanced". This changed the freezes. Now the system keeps working but after a while the mouse freezes. Could it be somehow related to the touchpad/mouse controllers? What is strange, is that when I plug-in a usb mouse, it also does not work. So I don't know how to interpret this.

I would very much appreciate any  advice on what else to try.